# jquery/jstree show child nodes initially

Tags: jquery, jstree

I'm using the [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/) jquery plugin to display and manage a tree. This is the json data:

```
0: {id:35, name:amrs trade, parent_id:null}
1: {id:36, name:trips, parent_id:35}
2: {id:37, name:tribute, parent_id:null}
3: {id:38, name:music, parent_id:null}
4: {id:39, name:recordings, parent_id:38}
5: {id:40, name:live shows, parent_id:38}
6: {id:41, name:others, parent_id:null}
7: {id:42, name:investments, parent_id:null}
8: {id:43, name:gold & silver, parent_id:42}
9: {id:44, name:debentures, parent_id:42}
10: {id:46, name:production, parent_id:35}
11: {id:54, name:real estate, parent_id:42}
```

that I'm using to create render my tree:

```
$("#incomeCategoryTree").jstree({
    "json_data" : {
        "data" : income,
        "progressive_render" : true
    },
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data" ]
})
```

I want to display the tree and to have it some chosen nodes opened initially (at now, only the top levels are displayed and all non-top-level nodes are hidden). What option can I add to above json to make jstree expand chosen nodes initially?

Answer (score 0):

state:`open`/`closed` does the job:

```
0: {id:35, name:amrs trade, parent_id:null, state:open}
1: {id:36, name:trips, parent_id:35}
2: {id:37, name:tribute, parent_id:null}
3: {id:38, name:music, parent_id:null}
4: {id:39, name:recordings, parent_id:38}
5: {id:40, name:live shows, parent_id:38}
6: {id:41, name:others, parent_id:null}
7: {id:42, name:investments, parent_id:null, state:closed}
8: {id:43, name:gold & silver, parent_id:42}
9: {id:44, name:debentures, parent_id:42}
10: {id:46, name:production, parent_id:35}
11: {id:54, name:real estate, parent_id:42}
```